ADT (ABAP) - Eclipse Project Explorer does not show the "Linked" object when it is open
I'm following SAP material where they are asking for you to find a class. According to instructions, if the "Linked with Editor" button is held, the Project Manager should open all the tree down to the open object.
However, this is not happening. And worst, the function do "duplicate" a class, for instance, it is only available when the object is shown IN THE TREE (what is a pain). Does anybody know whether this is related to some config on Eclipse so it works as expected?
=====================
Unfortunately I cannot post a screenshot due to machine restrictions. But what happens is that the ABAP tree doesn't appear, only Favorite Packages.
This is happening on SAP BTP provided environmet for study.

It has worked correctly as explained by the "instructions", for years. If your "worst" is a question if it exists duplication without selecting an object first, the answer is no.

Perhaps you could add a screenshot showing what you're talking about to the wider Eclipse audience since you are under the impression it's not specific to ABAP.

By design it doesn't open up the entire tree because there could be thousands of classes in there. CTRL + Shift + A will open the dialog to open any object, so start typing ZCL* and you can get to whatever class you want. Once the class is opened you can right click, Show In -> Project Explorer and it will open in the tree for you. Then you can click Duplicate to copy the class.

Even when I do as you said, when I click Show In > Project Explorer, it does nothing. I even tried to downgrade Eclipse version to the previous one, and got no results.

It looks like I have found a workaround: If I find out which package the ABAP resource is bound, and then add the package to the "Favorite Packages", then the "Link with Editor" button will work, only for that saved package.
